# Is the volume of blood pumped by the right and left ventricles the same?

Tags: cardiology, ventricles

Wikipedia says that the definition of stroke volume is:

> stroke volume (SV) is the volume of blood pumped from the left ventricle per beat

Why the left ventricle specifically? Why aren't both ventricles included in the definition?

Does this mean that the left ventricle pumps more/less blood (through the aorta) than the right ventricle (through the pulmonary artery)?

Comment: Your reference gives the left and right ventricle stroke volumes, which are the same. For all practical purposes, it has to be the same in healthy individuals; if it were not, blood would back up somewhere and oxygenation would decrease (this does happen in pathological situations.)  Why the left? Because that's the definition of stroke volume. (Circular argument. I don't actually know why, because cardiac output can be measured easily now on both sides.) I imagine there's a better reason, but I'm not a cardiologist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is under researched, unclear (title and body don't match), and  contains multiple questions. These are all reasons for downvoting and closure on this site. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details and delete or [edit] accordingly.